# Tomcat default page is not loaded on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, tomcat8

I installed Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 14.04. I started it from the terminal via tomcatup command and it is running. However, when I type localhost:8080 or 127.0.0.1:8080, the Tomcat 7 default page shows up on my browser. I redefined Catalina_home and JAVA_HOME variables inside the .bashrc file but the page still shows up. I am new to servlet programming and I have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: "the default page shows up"... Okay, so what is the problem?

Comment: And if you updated bashrc, you must `source` it for those changes to take effect

Comment: the default page is for Tomcat 7, I installed Tomcat 8. What do you mean by source?

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` is a Unix command. Type that on the terminal, see if that fixes anything

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to uninstall Tomcat7, or you need to configure the IP ports (in conf/server.xml) so that 7 and 8 do not get involved in a race for getting the same port first.

(BTW how did you know that it's the 7 page ?  I have tomcat on ubuntu as well but I don't recall ever having seen a version number on the root page ...)

Comment: yeah, I tried to make port 137 but the nothing was shown

Comment: (a) port 137 is known to be used by SMB, IIRC, and (b) never ever make services such as Tomcat listen on ports below 1024 (on many linux systems this would require root privileges and at any rate, there's a reason why those are called "reserved ports").

Comment: it was just white blank page without ant pics on it and it said that I successfully installed tomcat 7.  Anyway your advice did not work in my case, I tried to make port number 8081, but I recieve could not load page message. When I tried to make a simle servlet, eclipse give me an erreo message that it could not load tomcat 8 server configuration